# MonoDevelop/GTK OS X Usability Issues?

Tags: macos, gtk, osx-snow-leopard, monodevelop

Does anyone else have infuriating usability issues while trying to work with MonoDevelop in OS X Snow Leopard? The ones that interrupt my flow the most are associated with button clicks not responding until I move the window around a little bit. Afterwards, I can get maybe one or two button presses in before I have to repeat moving the window around.

I've heard this is a GTK problem that has nothing to do with MonoDevelop in the past and would like to know if anyone else experiences this or has found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few minor Mac-specific issues in MD, mostly due to the GTK toolkit. You will find some listed [in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com/buglist.cgi?bug_severity=Blocker&bug_severity=Critical&bug_severity=Major&bug_severity=Normal&bug_severity=Minor&classification=Mono&op_sys=Mac%20OS%20X%2010.4&op_sys=Mac%20OS%20X%2010.5&op_sys=Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6&query_format=advanced&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&bug_status=REOPENED&product=MonoDevelop), and others on the [known issues](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support#Known_Issues) page. The best place to ask about this stuff is on the [monodevelop mailing list](http://monodevelop.com/index.php?title=Help_%26_Contact) or, better, in the bug reports.

FWIW, I don't think you have to actually move the window to reset GTK's tracking, you just have to click on the window title bar.